# Does an RNN architecture exist where the output are actually samples drawn from a (non-parametric) probability distribution?

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks

Does an RNN architecture exist where my input is a 10 dimensional real-valued vector and the output are 200 samples drawn from a probability distribution.

In essence, the RNN is actually learning a probability distribution but gives the output as multiple (200) samples drawn from this distribution.

Comment: Could you explain why you might want this? It would seem easy to have the RNN output the learned distribution and then sample from it outside of the NN (which is e.g. how translation models based on LSTMs worked - although nowadays they are all transformers, the principle is the same). What benefit are you hoping to realise by having the RNN do the sampling via the NN architecture?

Comment: Let me try to provide more context: I have a model that gives me the distribution from t = 0 to ,say, t = T at an interval of 1 minute.  I also have a time series signal (10-dimensional) that is sampled every second. I want to predict the distribution using my time-series signal,  by training it on the time-series and distribution.

I chose an RNN with the time-series as input and the distribution as output. I am unsure how to use distribution as an output during training (drawing samples from this distribution and somehow using them as an output is what I was initially thinking).

Comment: Is your source distribution model inaccurate? I don't otherwise understand why you would take a full distribution ground truth and also want to use a sample?

Comment: I am making an assumption that the source distribution it is accurate. In the meanwhile efforts are underway to validate this assumption on a different data set. The source distribution I am using is a normalizing flow model.

Comment: If the distribution model that you are learning from is accurate ground truth, then *why* do you want a sample from it as well? A correct distribution model effectively contains the data from a large number of samples directly, in a single function call. I am not saying that you don't need to do this, or that your goal is wrong, but I am having trouble understanding from the question and your comments why you are doing this, and what you are hoping to achieve. If I cannot understand that then I don't think I can answer the question for you.

Comment: Am I right in guessing that your source distribution model is very expensive to calculate? So you want to create something approximate but faster? Otherwise I guess you would just take samples from the existing distribution model, and would not need to train any neural network.

Comment: The source distribution is not expensive. Once trained, it is actually quite cheap to draw samples.  But, the caveat is, the samples used to train the distribution generating model is obtained after a very long time interval. However, the time-series signals are obtained in real time.  So, we want to use the time series to understand the probability distribution at any given time. The source distribution simply serves as a surrogate data generator for the time series to learn some systems dynamics.

P.S.: I spent summer 2017 at Durham University and stayed by the cathedral. I loved it there.

Comment: Sorry I am missing something and don't understand your need/use-case. Maybe someone else can understand and help. There are several possible architectures that can sort of sample, and could be added to RNN-based approach. **None** of them learn to sample as a function, something has to be inserted into or extend the neural network. However, I am not sure if any of these would actually help you, and they might be hard to implement. PS I moved to Durham in 2015, and would go past the palace green (with castle and cathedral) a lot back then - so maybe we have even passed by one time!

Comment: Thank you for your attention Neil.